# PHP - Allowing string number and few symbols

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How to allow `preg_replace` string, number and few symbols?

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$data[0]); //only works fine for numbers
```

columns values are:

```
Technische achtergrond,0,1
Maritieme bediende,1,1
Transport rijbewijs C en CE,0,4
Commercieel bediende,1,5
Heftruck/Reachtruck(technisch operator),0,5
Boukhouding/Financieel,1,3
```

Comment: What are your actual requirements? Can you define your requirements clearly

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) !

Comment: Try as `^[A-Z][a-z]+\/[A-Z][a-z]+\(.*\),\d,\d$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z\(\),/\-\.'\" ]#i", "", $data[0]);
```

Comment: @M0rtiis It's more worthwhile to teach someone than do it for them :)